# Wordpress/PHP: Can't get WordPress posts to order by year/date

Tags: php, wordpress

I've grouped my posts by year...but it's showing the earliest yearsection  first e.g. 2013 and not 2015...

2013
2014
2015

It shoul dbe

2015
2014
2013

Here is the code:

```
$year_check = date('Y', strtotime($post->post_date));
            if($year_tmp!==$year_check){
                $year_tmp = $year_check;

                if($postsShown > 0){
                    echo '</div>';
                }

                echo '<div class="seperator"></div><a href="#" class="datecolumn" id="date_col_'.$year_check.'">'.$year_check.'<div class="expand" id="expand_'.$year_check.'">CLOSE</div></a><div class="seperator"></div><div class="ruler"></div><div class="seperator"></div><div class="yearBlock" id="'.$year_check.'">';
            }

            $date = date('jS F Y', strtotime($post->post_date));

            echo '<a class="standardColumnLink" href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" title="'.$thetitle.'">';

            if(!empty($thethumb)){
                echo '<div class="standardColumnImage">'.$thethumb.'</div>';
            }

            echo '<div class="columncopy"><div class="narrowcolumn">&rarr;</div><div class="titles">'.$thetitle.'</div><div class="columnbody">'.get_excerpt_by_id(get_the_ID()).'</div><div class="columdate"><strong>Date posted:</strong> '.$date.'</div></div></a>';

            if($year_tmp!==$year_check){
                echo '</div>';
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely right, it was i the query logic... I changed the orderby to DESC and it worked.

Thank you.